# Laravel, millions of rows inserts and searches

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

So, I need to insert millions of rows in database with seeder using faker.

And eventually, to search them, for example: 3+ million people and search them by name.

How to achieve this using Laravel?

Comment: what is "seeder" and "faker" ? how is it related to the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seed your tables using something like the following; this example uses model factories to conveniently generate large amounts of users, first, create your `UsersTableSeeder`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(User::class, 1000)->create()->each(function() {
            factory(User::class)->make();
        });
    }
}
```

In your `ModelFactory`:

```
use App\User;

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'role' => rand(1, 3),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

To run the seeder, open your `DatabaseSeeder` class and add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * if you get Reflection Exception: Seeder class not found, dump autoload files.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Then, using the command line, run:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Then just perform queries to obtain them, for example:

```
User::where('first_name','Joe') -> first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Laravel Scout with Algolia for a search index.
You can keep it in sync with the model.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout